# Ranking by median in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am newish to pandas. I have a dataframe (df) with the columns, height (numeric) and team (string) I'd like to rank the teams by their median height.

Here is what I have done so far

```
df = old_df.groupby("team")
a=df["height"].agg([np.median])
a=a.sort_values(by=['median'])
a.reset_index(inplace=True)
b=a["team"].tolist()
```

this outputs a list of the team names (b), in order of median height, which could be converted into a dictionary and used to create a new col of the data frame. I am not sure how to do that, but my intuition is that there is almost certainly a simpler way of doing this.

Can you see a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to group the teams before computing/sorting their medians:

```py
df.groupby('team')['height'].agg('median').sort_values()
```

---

Toy example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['foo']*3 + ['bar']*2, 'height': [1,3,7,20,40]})

#   team  height
# 0  foo       1
# 1  foo       3
# 2  foo       7
# 3  bar      20
# 4  bar      40
```

```py
ranked = df.groupby('team')['height'].agg('median').sort_values()

# team
# foo     3
# bar    30
# Name: height, dtype: int64
```

```py
ranked.to_dict()

# {'foo': 3, 'bar': 30}
```

---

**Update:** To compute the ranks explicitly, use [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```py
ranked = df.groupby('team')['height'].agg('median').rank(ascending=False)

# team
# bar    1.0
# foo    2.0
# Name: height, dtype: float64
```

```py
ranked.to_dict()

# {'bar': 1.0, 'foo': 2.0}
```

Comment: this code produces a Series. you can add `.reset_index()` to make a DataFrame, or `.to_dict()` to make a dictionary, etc.

Comment: if i use .reset_index.to_dict it gives me a dictionary containing mapping the column names (team names, heights) to the dictionaries mapping the rank number to the column elements i.e. {1 : harlem_globetrotters, ...} and {1 : 7.0, ...} how do i get a dictionary like {harlem_globetrotters:1, chicago_bulls:2} ?

Comment: for that, use only `.to_dict()` without resetting: `df.groupby('team')['height'].agg(np.median).sort_values().to_dict()`

Comment: that gives me a dictionary going from team name to median height e.g. {harlem_globetrotters:7.0, chicago_bulls 6.9, ....} - I am looking for team name to team rank  {harlem_globetrotters:1, chicago_bulls:2}